# Why is STM32 header file using unsigned int instead of unsigned long?

Tags: c, stm32

Below is from a header file of a STM32 microcontroller board:

```
#define RCC_APB2RSTR_USART1RST_Pos               (14U)                         
#define RCC_APB2RSTR_USART1RST_Msk               (0x1UL << RCC_APB2RSTR_USART1RST_Pos) /*!< 0x00004000 */
```

At first line when I hover on 4U it shows it as "unsigned int"; the second line used UL which is "unsigned long".

But according to [this page](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125009502.htm) both "unsigned int" and "unsigned  long" are same (both being 32-bit and unsigned integers ):

[image]

What could be the reason they don't follow the same types here? Why not using 14UL but 14U even though they are same?

Comment: Value `14` can fit in byte (8 bits) not in 32/64 bits. What is the reason to ask for `long`?

Comment: There is no reason for the operands of a shift to have the same type; it is a heterogeneous operation where the type of the right operand (how much to shift) is not related to the type of the left operand (data to be shifted). This differs from homogenous operations such as `+`, `-`, or `*` where the two operands interact. `unsigned int` provides values up to at least 65,535, and that is more than sufficient for any reasonable shift amount or number of bits. The name `RCC_APB2RSTR_USART1RST_Pos` suggests it is a position value, that is, a bit number. So `unsigned int` suffices.

Comment: You say unsigned int provides values up to at least 65,535. If so I would not ask this question. The link I provided shows unsigned int is same for unsigned long for ARM.

Comment: These numbers server very different purpose. Why should they have the same type? I doubt you will find many CPUs where the valid range for shift count does not fit into a `char`.

Comment: @GNZ registers in the STM32 are 32 bits wide which requires 4 bytes, for portability reasons its unsigned long even though you should never have a problem with unsigned int with the STM32 platform. If you move to an 8-bit platform or 16-bit platform with the same code its wasted space and instruction time.

Compilers can also specify their own sizes (looking at you Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Although unsigned int is usually always 4 bytes (32-bit arch), the spec states it only has to be at minimum 2 bytes. Unsigned long is spec'd to be minimum of 4 bytes. When shifting like above its less likely for an overflow to happen since those are probably copy/pasted or auto generated from a script. Its also possible its a typo.